# Android - context with MVP

Tags: android, view, mvp, android-context, presenter

I'm about creating a simple app with MVP implementation, and trying to make a permission request in a presenter. To make a permission request, I need to pass Context like this.

```
        // Location permission has not been granted yet, request it.
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(fragmentActivity, new String[]{permission}, requestId);
```

I've read several articles and they mention that using Context in a presenter is not a good exercise. So, I'm just wondering how people are handling a permission request with MVP. And I don't really know why using Context in a presenter is not good practice.
Please, help me to understand how I should handle a permission request and why using context is not good practice.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must never send any object related to Android to the presenter layer, and they must be fully decoupled.

to do these things I always remember a good sentence and that goes `Do not inject objects, inject operations and behavior`.

it so simple dont inject your context into your presenter which is a wrong practice. instead in your view contract (view interface) add a function called `getPermission()` then in your view implement that method along with other methods of your contract, then call that method whenever you need the permission.

thats the best way. trust me ;)

Comment: Thanks for replying Amir. So, other context required methods like getResource should be in view(Activity or Fragment) side, right? Now, I have other line in my presenter that is getting string array from strings.xml resource. But without contest, I cannot get string resources and cannot create string. In that case what do you do?

Comment: How about when you open an external app from presenter with context.startActivity(intent) ?   I was passing a context from view to my presenter and do  context.startActivity(intent).

Comment: look its so easy. every little thing can be done through interfaces. create an interface containing `startSomeActivity()` and `getSomeString()` in your presenter layer then implement these in your view layer then send the implementation to the pesenter. then presenter will triiger the actions whenever it needs to.

Comment: Yes, it's easy, whenever you need to use Context let View do the work. But I was trying to give more clear role to view and presenter.  View is just displaying what presenter says. So, what I'm doing is.. Presenter get data from model layer and/or  resource. Then the presenter creates strings to display. Finally, presenter pass those strings to view layer.

Comment: if its a message to show the status pf application like "error happened !" or "connection error !" it should be in resources in view layaer and there must be some methods like `showConnectionError()` which view implements. but for other strings like what you get from database the source of string is model and then presenter to the view ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple flavors of MVP out there in practice. I am not here to start a debate which one is right and which one is wrong. As long as a particular flavor works for your scenario, it shall be used.

Instead, I will try to explain why the context in Presenter should be avoided and one of the ways I have avoided in my code.

One of the major reason you should not have a context in the presenter, there might be references to presenter which could leak the activity. In places where I had to deal with a context within the activity, I have accessed through Views.

```
interface View {
   Context getContext();
}

interface Presenter {
   void setView(View view);
}
```

So PresenterImpl implements a view, onCreate of the activity and resets it onDestroy of the activity. So the presenter never directly holds the context. But it holds the view, which has knowledge about the View.